# How far would a Boom gun propel a Glitter Boy if the jetpack and anchors were disabled?

Tags: movement, rifts, dodge, mecha

The Palladium Rifts Glitter Boy Boom gun accelerates a flechette round of ammo at over Mach One. Normally, laser tipped anchors from the legs drill into the ground and a jetpack provides counter thrust to offset the recoil.

If both of these safety mechanisms were disabled, how far would the gun propel the Glitter Boy power armor in earth normal gravity at one atmosphere pressure?

A player wants to use a prepared action to "offensively dodge" an anticipated enemy action.

Comment: @PotatoEngineer Please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disengaging the safety measures means flying backward 30 ft. and being rendered prone upon firing the Boom Gun

*Rifts Ultimate Edition* (2010) on the **RG–14 Rapid Acceleration Electromagnetic Rail Gun** says, "The blast [emitted by the Boom Gun] is so powerful that without the automatic stabilization system, the Glitter Boy would be thrown to the ground and knocked back 30 feet" (72).

I have no idea what this information means for the PC's "offensive dodge."